# Segmentation fault (core dumped) in programme in c?

Tags: c, typedef, c-strings

I'm a student and I m learning c (programming in ANSI c -> fifth edition) and facing the below error:

I'm implementing one program with typedef

In below c program give an error:

```
main.c:8:6: warning: ‘gets’ is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]                                                                                                      
/usr/include/stdio.h:638:14: note: declared here                                                                                                                           
main.c:(.text+0x1f): warning: the `gets' function is dangerous and should not be used.                                                                                     
enter name:cara                                                                                                                                                            
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

char * read(void);   //here I m writing prototype but I don't know what is the prototype and why here write the prototype?
char * read(void)
{
     char * name;
     printf("enter name:");
     gets(name);  //get string input using gets(..) function
     return name;
}

void main()
{
   char * name;
   name = read();
   printf("welcome,%s\n",name);
}
```

above program is a complexity that is why I m using typedef in the below program:

**this below program continuously run why**?

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef char * string;

string read(void);   
string read(void)
{
     string name;
     printf("enter name:");
     gets(name); 
     return name;
}

void main()
{
   string name;
   name = read();
   printf("welcome,%s\n",name);
}
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of things wrong with this. When you do `char * name`, you define `name` as a char pointer, but you don't actually allocate any space for the string to be stored. Hence, when you try to write values into that string, you're writing values in a random place that may not be writable or may contain crucial data that cannot be overwritten. Instead, try declaring name as `char name[256];` to allocate enough space for it. Also, don't use `gets`, as it can lead to very, very, nasty things. Instead, use `fgets` to read input, and provide an upper limit on the number of characters equal to the amount of data you allocated. So, if you declared name as `char name[256];`, call fgets with `fgets(name, 256, stdin);`

Comment: as per your suggestion I m follow your suggestion but still not fix the error in my program https://wandbox.org/permlink/nBjlqxNdtHPtyMT9 please help

Answer (score 0):

The program has undefined behavior because you are using an uninitialized pointer that has an indeterminate value

```
 char * name;
 printf("enter name:");
 gets(name);
```

You need to allocate memory where you are going to read a string.

As for the function `gets`  then it is indeed an unsafe function and is not supported by the C Standard anymore. Use instead the standard C function `fgets`.

Pay attention to that according to the C Standard the function main without parameters shall be declared like

```
int main( void )
```

And using a typedef like this

```
typedef char * string;
```

is a bad idea. For example using this typedef name you are unable to declare a pointer to constant data like

```
const char *p;
```

because this declaration

```
const string p;
```

is not equivalent to the above declaration but means the following declaration

```
char * const p;
```

The program can look for example the following way

```
#include <stdio.h>

char * read( char *s, size_t n )
{
    s[0] = '\0';

    printf( "Enter name: " );
    fgets( s, n, stdin );

    return s;
}

int main( void )
{
    enum { N = 100 };

   char name[N];

    printf( "%s", read( name, N ) );
}
```

Its output might look like

```
Enter name: rahul_
rahul_
```

Pay attention to that the function `fgets` can append the entered string with the new line character `'\n'`. To remove it you can use the following trick

```
#include <string.h>

//...

name[ strcspn( name, "\n" ) ] = '\0';
```

Comment: thanks for detailing explanation but does not understand this line ```s[0] = '\0';``` and this line ```enum { N = 100 };```

Comment: @rahul_ Try never use magic numbers like 100. Use named constant. So the enumeration introduces named constant N equal to 100 that specifies the size of the character array.  s[0] = '\0'; initializes the array by an empty string. If fgets is failed then the function returns an empty string instead of indeterminate value.